# Trying to use subscribing event processor and tracking event processor in axon config together

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I am trying to use Subscribing Event Processor and Tracking Event Processor in Axon config together without success. I am only able to use Subscribing Event Processor.

I am using Axon Framework 4.x version with Spring Boot

```java
@Autowired
public void registerTrackingProcessorConfig(EventProcessingConfigurer processingConfigurer) {
    TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration tepConfig = 
        TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration.forSingleThreadedProcessing();
    processingConfigurer.registerTrackingEventProcessorConfiguration(
        "myTrackingProcessorGroup", 
        config -> tepConfig
    );
}
         
    
@Autowired
public void configure(EventProcessingConfigurer config) {
    config.usingSubscribingEventProcessors();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the piece of code you shared.

Looking at the `EventProcessingConfigurer` [API](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/axonframework/config/EventProcessingConfigurer.java), you have:

- `registerTrackingEventProcessor`
- `registerSubscribingEventProcessor`
- `registerPooledStreamingEventProcessor`

All of them will register an `EventProcessor` with the given type and you can read more about those on the [ref guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors).

Another way to do that is to use a `properties` or `yml` file, like so:

```
axon.eventhandling.processors.my-subscribing-processor.mode=subscribing
axon.eventhandling.processors.my-tracking-processor.mode=tracking
axon.eventhandling.processors.my-pooled-processor.mode=pooled
```

For the last config you shared (`config.usingSubscribingEventProcessors();`), this is the default type in case you do not register an `EventHandler` with an explicit type.